# Cannot manipulate text after /following-sibling with XPATH and PHP

Tags: php, xpath

Hello im trying to manipulate the text after expression with XPATH and PHP, but do not work.

```
->query('//th[contains(., "Code")]/following-sibling::*[1]')
```

Result:

```
111,222,333
```

Expected :

```
222,333
```

Or perfect would have this exploded in array for further manipulation

```
[111]
[222]
[333]
```

I've been tried this without success:

```
->query('//th[contains(., "Code")]/following-sibling::*[substring-after(.,",")]')

->query('substring-after(/th[contains(., "Code")]/following-sibling::*[1],",")')

->query('//th[contains(., "Code")]/substring-after(/following-sibling::*[1],",")')
```

Any help to fix this please? Many Thanks

Comment: Can you show the actual HTML you are parsing?

Comment: Sure:

 `<tr>
 <th>
  Code
 </th>
 <td>
  36247, 38254, 95006, 095013
 </td>
</tr>`

Comment: what do u expect to get from this HTML?

Comment: I would like to walk in this query with the function substring-after skipping everything prior the first comma, something like substring-after(.,",")

`38254, 95006, 095013`

Comment: @ecmoura understood, solution has been provided.

Answer (score 0):

That must work for you

```
substring-after(/tr/th[.='Code']/following-sibling::td, ',')
```

Minor improvement which you may need (delete spaces before and after)

```
normalize-space(substring-after(/tr/th[.='Code']/following-sibling::td, ','))
```

Comment: Unfortunately don't work . It returns an empty string. If i remove the function i get the resuls, obviously not manipulated.

Comment: Thanks Dmytro. Your answers is also valid, except i had to replace single to doube slash.

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath expression which using `susbstring-after()` function looks promising. But note that [`DOMXPath::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) unable to return other than node-set. For executing xpath expression that doesn't return node-set, i.e `substring-after()` function, use [`DOMXPath::evaluate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php) instead :

```
$xpath->evaluate('substring-after(//th[contains(., "Code")]/following-sibling::*[1],",")');
```

Comment: `<?php

    $body='<html><head>
  <title>xpath test</title></head><body><table><tr> <th>Code</th> <td> 36247, 38254, 95006, 095013 </td> </tr></table></body></html>';  


$DOM = new \DOMDocument();  
$DOM->loadHTML($body);  
$xpath = new \DomXPath($DOM);  

$nodes=$xpath->evaluate('substring-after(/th[contains(., "Code")]/following-sibling::*[1],",")');
  
print_r($nodes); //returns empty`

Comment: Hello, this is my full code and the results is always empty.

Could you check what i'm doing wrong? Sorry for the messy code, i don't how to format it here. @dmytro-pastovenskyi

Comment: Sorry, I currrently have limited access through mobile phone. For a quick fix, use //tr instead of /tr in your xpath, since the target tr element is not the root of the document